# Opening a second python file (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have two programs that I want to be able to combine but I can't seem to work out how. The first program is a homepage/menu (*studious_main.py*) and on it there is a button (*btnLearn*) which, when clicked, should (hopefully) close the window and open the second program *studious_create.py*.

```
btnLearn = Button(container2, image = imgLearnBtn,command=destroy).pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = 100)
```

(Currently it just closes the window.)

How would you recommend I go about getting the program to do this? I'm still very much a novice and I just can't seem to wrap my head around the problem, sorry

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a function that will handle the operations you need done, then bind the `command` of your button to it.

```
def close_current_and_open_other():
    # code to close the current: destroy(), etc...
    # code to open the second program

btnLearn = Button(container2, image=imgLearnBtn, command=close_current_and_open_other).pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=100)
```

Comment: how would I open the second program, is there a command for that?

Comment: It is hard to say without a better understanding of what exactly the problem is... Maybe you want to ask another question where you explain the specifics of it?

Comment: I have just posted a new question with the code I am working on - I hope it makes sense, let me know if you need more context.